# MYSQL <> operator instead of NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

How can I make this answer  by using `<>` instead of `NOT IN`

```
SELECT ward_no, COUNT(patient_id) AS occupying
FROM patient
WHERE ward_no NOT IN ('w5', 'w7')
GROUP BY ward_no
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
SELECT ward_no, COUNT(patient_id) AS occupying
FROM patient
WHERE ward_no <> 'w5' AND ward_no <> 'w7'
GROUP BY ward_no
```

But it's way heavier than a simple NOT IN, so I wouldn't do that myself.

Comment: broo I have some misconcept about group by so can you please help me to get the point of group by I have this answer if you want to explain it:SELECT course_code, student_id, AVG(mark) AS avg_mark
FROM assignment
WHERE course_code NOT IN ('c4', 'c7')
AND assignment_number <> '3'
GROUP BY course_code, student_id
HAVING AVG(mark) > 70

Comment: the question of this answer is : Example: For each course, except c4 and c7, list those students whose average mark for all assignments, not including assignment 3, is over 70. Also, list the average marks for these students. 
SO why we put in the group by the student-id and course code not just one of them

Comment: Rule of thumb : When you use an aggregate function (avg, max, etc...), you have to GROUP BY all the non aggregated columns in your SELECT. ex : SELECT a, b, c, max(d), you have to group by a, b and c.

Comment: ok but as a concept of group by what does it mean or what it do sorry for asking you many questions

Comment: In your example (ward_no, COUNT(patient_id), it will return one row for each ward_no and count the patients instead of returning one row for each pair ward_no-patient_id. Please read [some GROUP BY doc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT ward_no, COUNT(patient_id) AS occupying
FROM patient
WHERE ward_no <> 'w5' AND ward_no <> 'w7'
GROUP BY ward_no
```

Comment: Lover I read your profile and I was interested by your skills and helping others so please sir how can I always talk with you when I need to ask you questions I tried to enter your websites to connect with you

Comment: @Marwan you can invite me in chat. or can leave a comment on my website or blog.

Comment: @Marwan you can invite me here for chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1035257/code-lver

Comment: its the first time I use the stackoverflow I don't know to invite you to a room

Comment: marwan.dalaty@hotmail.com send me your email if you want thanks sir for your help

Comment: @Marwan my mail id is vashishtha.gaurav5@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Answer from here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html

NOT IN is an alias for <> ALL. Thus, these two statements are the same:

```
SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 <> ALL (SELECT s1 FROM t2);
SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 NOT IN (SELECT s1 FROM t2);
```